# NSURLProtocol registerClass works for iOS simulator but not actual device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlprotocol, cronet

I am calling `[NSURLProtocol registerClass]` to use a custom protocol (Chromium Cronet) when playing a video using `AVPlayer`.  (The register is done at [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/cronet/ios/Cronet.mm#399): )

It works well on iOS simulator (Xcode 11.3) but when runs on an actual device (iPhone SE, iOS 13), the custom protocol was not triggered. (i.e. it's `canInitWithRequest` method was not called).

My question: what is the possible reason to cause different behavior between iOS simulator and real device in the case of `[NSURLProtocol registerClass]` ?  Anything I can do to fix that for real device?

Comment: Now I suspect this might be related to whether `AVPlayer` uses the shared NSURLSession object.  Anyone knows if `AVPlayer` uses the shared NSURLSession?  and whether it depends on env?

Comment: i too have the same issue. did u got the answer

Comment: @Marios no I didn't get answer. I am using a workaround / solution that implements my own delegate `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate`.  See this one from me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60179072/avplayer-url-custom-loading-for-https